# Running time of Kruskal's algorithm

Tags: performance, time, graph, kruskals-algorithm

The Kruskal's algorithm is the following:

```
MST-KRUSKAL(G,w)
1. A={}
2. for each vertex v∈ G.V
3.      MAKE-SET(v)
4. sort the edges of G.E into nondecreasing order by weight w
5. for each edge (u,v) ∈ G.E, taken in nondecreasing order by weight w
6.      if FIND-SET(u)!=FIND-SET(v)   
7.         A=A U {(u,v)}  
8.         Union(u,v)
9. return A
```

According to my textbook:

> Initializing the set A in line 1 takes O(1) time, and the time to sort
>   the edges in line 4 is O(E lgE). The for loop of lines 5-8 performs
>   O(E) FIND-SET and UNION operations on the disjoint-set forest. Along
>   with the |V| MAKE-SET operations, these take a total of O((V+E)α(V))
>   time, where α is a very slowly growing function. Because we assume
>   that G is connected, we have |E| <= |V|-1, and so the disjoint-set
>   operations take O(E α(V)) time. Moreover, since α(V)=O(lgV)=O(lgE),
>   the total running time of Kruskal's algorithm is O(E lgE). Observing
>   that |E|<|V|^2, we have lg |E|=O(lgV), and so we can restate the
>   running time of Kruskal's algorithm as O(E lgV).

Could you explain me why we deduce that the time to sort the edges in line 4 is O(E lgE)?
Also how do we get that the total time complexity is  O((V+E)α(V)) ?

In addition, suppose that all edge weights in a graph are integers from 1 to |V|. How fast can you make Kruskal's algorithm run? What if the edges weights are integers in the range from 1 to W for some constant W?

How does the time complexity depend on the weight of the edges?

**EDIT**:

> In addition, suppose that all edge weights in a graph are integers
>   from 1 to |V|. How fast can you make Kruskal's algorithm run?

I have thought the following:

In order the Kruskal's algorithm to run faster, we can sort the edges applying Counting Sort.

- The line 1 requires O(1) time.
- The lines 2-3 require O(v) time.
- The line 4 requires O(|V|+|E|) time.
- The lines 5-8 require O(|E|α(|V|)) time.
- The line 9 requires O(1) time.

So if we use Counting Sort in order to solve the edges, the time complexity of Kruskal will be

[image]

Could you tell me if my idea is right?

Also:

> What if the edges weights are integers in the range from 1 to W for
>   some constant W?

We will again use Counting Sort. The algorithm will be the same. We find the time complexity as follows:

- The line 1 requires O(1) time.
- The lines 2-3 require O(|V|) time.
- The line 4 requires O(W+|E|)=O(W)+O(|E|)=O(1)+O(|E|)=O(|E|) time.
- The lines 5-8 require O(|E|α(|V|)) time.
- The line 9 requires O(1) time.

So the time complexity will be:

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Could you explain me why we deduce that the time to sort the edges in line 4 is O(E*lgE)?

To sort a set of N items we use O(N*lg(N)) algorithm, which is quick sort, merge sort or heap sort. To sort E edges we therefore need O(E*lg(E)) time. This however is not necessary in some cases, as we could use sorting algorithm with better complexity (read further).

> Also how do we get that the total time complexity is O((V+E)α(V))?

I don't think total complexity is O((V+E)α(V)). That would be complexity of the 5-8 loop. O((V+E)α(V)) complexity comes from V MAKE-SET operations and E Union operations. To find out why we multiply that with α(V) you will need to read in depth analysis of disjoint set data structure in some algorithmic book.

> How fast can you make Kruskal's algorithm run?

For first part, line 4, we have O(E*lg(E)) complexity and for second part, line 5-8, we have O((E+V)*α(V)) complexity. This two summed up yield O(E*lg(E)) complexity. If we use O(N*lg(N)) sort this can't be improved.

> What if the edges weights are integers in the range from 1 to W for
>   some constant W?

If that is the case, than we could use counting sort for first part. Giving line 4 complexity of O(E+W) = O(E). In that case algorithm would have O((E+V)*α(V)) total complexity. Note that however O(E + W) in reality includes a constant that could be rather large and might be impractical for large W.

> How does the time complexity depend on the weight of the edges?

As said, if weight of the edges is small enough we can use counting sort and speed up the algorithm.

> EDIT:
>
> In addition, suppose that all edge weights in a graph are integers
>   from 1 to |V|. How fast can you make Kruskal's algorithm run? I have
>   thought the following:
>
> In order the Kruskal's algorithm to run faster, we can sort the edges
>   applying Counting Sort.
>
> The line 1 requires O(1) time. The lines 2-3 require O(vα(|V|)) time.
>   The line 4 requires O(|V|+|E|) time. The lines 5-8 require
>   O(|E|α(|V|)) time. The line 9 requires O(1) time.

Your idea is correct, however you can make bounds smaller.

The lines 2-3 requires O(|V|) rather than O(|V|α(|V|)). We however simplified it to O(|V|α(|V|)) in previous calculations to make calculations easier.

With this you get the time of:
O(1) + O(|V|) + O(|V| + |E|) + O(|E|α(|V|)) + O(1) = O(|V| + |E|) + O(|E|α(|V|))

You can simplify this to either O((|V| + |E|) * α(|V|) or to O(|V| + |E|*α(|V|).

So while you were correct, since O((|V| + |E|) * α(|V|) < O((|V| + |E|) * lg(|E|)

Calculations for the |W| are analogous.

Comment: Riko You said that "O((V+E)α(V))  would be the complexity of the 5-8 loop. O((V+E)α(V)) complexity comes from V MAKE-SET operations and E Union operations." But at this for-loop we don't have MAKE-SET operations. So do we also take into consideration the other for-loop? If so, why could we do so although the number of times that the two for-loops are executed isn't the same? 

Also you said that for the line 4 we have O(E*lgE) complexity and for line 5-8 we have O((E+V)α(V)) complexity. So don't we take into consideration the first for-loop? And how if we sum these two up, do we get O(E*lgE) ?

Comment: Also, what does N represent at the time complexity O(N*lg(N)) ?


Furthermore, can we only use counting sort at the case when the edge weights are integers in the range from 1 to W but not when they are in the range from 1 to |V|? If so, why is it like that? 


Also, why would the complexity of line 4 be O(E+W) ?

Comment: Yes, my bad, you also need to count first loop. Lines 2-3 and 5-8 together would than yield O((V+E)α(V)) complexity. If we sum O(ElgE) and O((E+V)α(V)) we get O(ElgE) because O((E+V)α(V)) < O(ElgE).

Comment: N represents number of elements that we sort. It doesn't matter in what range they are, but that range should be reasonable small. To understand counting sort better read about it here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_sort

Comment: Riko So is the time complexity of the lines 2-3 equal to O(Vα(V)) ? Also is it like that? O(ElgE)+O((E+V)α(V))=O(ElgE)+O((V+E)*lgE), since α(V)=O(lgE) and O(ElgE)+O((V+E)*lgE)=O(E*lgE+V*lgE+E*lgE)=O((V+E)*lgE).

Then we know that |E|<=|V|-1, because we assume that G is connected. So isn't it as follows? (V+E)*lgE<=(2V-1)*lgE=O(V*lgE) or am I wrong? How do we deduce that O(ElgE)+O((E+V)α(V))=O(E*lgE) ?

Comment: Yes and yes, your calculations are correct to the point where you assume |E| <= |V|-1. If the graph is connected we know that number of edges is at least |V| - 1. Making that equation |E| >= |V|-1. If you change that you will get O(Elg(E))

Comment: Oh, yes, Riko, you are right... Since |E|>=V-1 we have (V+E)*lgE<=(2E+1)*lgE=O(E*lgE). I found this: "Counting sort assumes that each of the n imput elements is an integer in the range 0 to k, for some integer k. When k=O(n), the sort runs in Θ(n) time." Doesn't this mean that the line 4 requires Θ(W) time? Or have I understood it wrong?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74966/discussion-between-evinda-and-riko).

Comment: Riko, I edited my post. Could you take a look at it?

Comment: Riko, could you explain me further why the lines 2-3 require O(V) rather than O(Vα(|V|))?

Comment: You have to create V sets. To create one set you spend O(1), therefore you need V * O(1) = O(V) to create V of them.

Comment: Riko Ok, I will.. Is it known that MAKE-SET(v) requires constant time or do we have to prove it? If it takes constant time, is it because of the fact that it is like we put an element in a list?

Comment: No need to prove it. It is similar to putting element to list. It just creates empty set so it surely has constant time, as it always takes the same time.

Comment: Correct, but there is no need to replace alpha(V) with lg(V), with that you are just killing precision of result.

Comment: Riko Nice.. Thank you very much!!! :-) Could you maybe also take a look at this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29594568/running-time-of-prims-algorithm Do you have an idea how fast we can make Prim's algorithm run? What can we do?

Comment: No need to thank me :) just upvote and accept :) as far as the other question is concerned, amalsom gave good answer, that I upvoted, not much to add.

Comment: No, I found this: http://www.eng-hs.net/files/Algorithms-Solutions-CH-23.pdf and at page 17, they found that the time complexity is O(E α(V)) . How did they get rid of V at O(V+E+Eα(V)) ? @Riko

Comment: V < E, therefore O(V) < O(E). We also know that O(E) = O(Eα(V)).

Comment: V<=E-1 holds only if the graph G is connected, right? So do we suppose it?

Comment: Yes, we suppose it is connected, since if it isn't you can't find spanning tree anyways.

Comment: Riko, could you take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29871890/time-complexity-of-modified-dfs-algorithm ?