# Time Complexity of modified dfs algorithm

Tags: graph, time-complexity, depth-first-search

I want to write an algorithm that finds an optimal vertex cover of a tree in linear time O(n), where n is the number of the vertices of the tree.

A vertex cover of a graph G=(V,E) is a subset W of V such that for every edge (a,b) in E, a is in W or b is in W.

In a vertex cover we need to have at least one vertex for each edge.

If we pick a non-leaf, it can cover more than one edge.

That's why I thought we can do it as follows:

We visit the root of the tree, then we visit one of its children, a child of the latter that we visited and so on.

Then if we have reached at a leaf, we check if we already have taken its father for the optimal vertex cover, and if not we pick it. Then, if the vertex that we picked for the optimal vertex cover has also other children, we pick the first of them and visit the leftmost children recursively and if we reach at the leaf and its father hasn't been chosen for the desired vertex cover, we choose it and so on.

I have written the following algorithm:

```
   DFS(node x){
      discovered[x]=1;
      for each (v in Adj(x)){
          if discovered[v]==0{
             DFS(v);
             if (v->taken==0){
                 x<-taken=1;
             }
          }
      }
    }
```

I thought that its time complexity is

[image]

(|V_i|, |E_i| are the number of vertices and edges respectively of the subtrees at the root of which we call DFS )

Is the time complexity I found right? Or have I calculated it wrong?

**EDIT**: Is the complexity of the algorithm described by the recurrence relation:

T(|V|)=E*T(|V|-1)+O(1)

? Or am I wrong?

Comment: Vertex cover is an NP-Complete problem. I hope you realize your algorithm would only work for a tree.

Comment: Also, since it's a tree - can't you just pick the even and the odd depths for the vertex cover? Is there any case that's not optimal anyway?

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum So if the height of the tree is odd, do we pick the vertices of the even depths for the optimal vertex cover and if the height of the tree is even, we pick the vertices of the odd depths?

Comment: @evdina you pick the lower between the number of even depth vertices and odd depth vertices, depending on the data layout that's probably an `O(1)` solution.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum So does this mean that we have to look for the height of the given tree and if this is odd there are less even depth vertices and if the height is even the number of even depth vertices is the same as the number of odd depth vertices?

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum Or have I understood it wrong? If so, how can we calculate the number of even depth vertices and the number of odd depth vertices?

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum What vertex do you pick as the root? This doesn't work. Take two stars of degree 10, connect their centers with a path of length 3. The two optimal solutions are picking both centers and either vertex in the "middle" of the path, neither of which we get regardless of which vertex we pick as root since we necessarily have to pick two neighboring vertices (one center and its neighbor on the path), one of which must be on an even level and the other on an odd level.

Comment: See [this question on CS.SE](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/12177/correctness-proof-of-a-greedy-algorithm-for-minimum-vertex-cover-of-a-tree) for a solution.

Comment: @G.Bach The algorithm is the same as mine, right? Could we maybe find a tighter upper bound?

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum Do you have an idea if there is a tighter upper bound for the modified dfs algorithm?

Comment: It looks to be the same as yours, yes. A tight bound of `O(|V| + |E|)` is easy to derive since it's just DFS with a constant amount of overhead at each node.

Comment: How do we deduce that a tight bound is `O(|V|+|E|)` ? @G.Bach

Comment: See my last comment. If you'd like to know how to derive that bound for DFS, there should be loads of proofs for that online somewhere.