# Time complexity of union

Tags: algorithm, union, time-complexity, dijkstra

We have a directed graph G=(V,E) ,at which each edge (u, v) in E has a relative value r(u, v) in R and 0<=r(u, v) <= 1, that represents the reliability , at a communication channel, from the vertex u to the vertex v.

Consider as r(u, v) the probability that the chanel from u to v will not fail the transfer and that the probabilities are independent.
I want to write an efficient algorithm that finds the most reliable path between two given nodes.

I have tried the following:

```
DIJKSTRA(G,r,s,t)
1.  INITIALIZE-SINGLE-SOURCE(G,s)
2.  S=Ø
3.  Q=G.V
4.  while Q != Ø
5.         u<-EXTRACT-MAX(Q)
6.         if (u=t) return d[t]
7.         S<-S U {u}
8.         for each vertex v in  G.Adj[u]
9.             RELAX(u,v,r)


INITIAL-SINGLE-SOURCE(G,s)
1. for each vertex v  in  V.G
2.      d[v]=-inf
3.      pi[v]=NIL
4. d[s]=1



RELAX(u,v,r)
 1. if d[v]<d[u]*r(u,v)
 2   d[v]<-d[u]*r(u,v)
 3.   pi[v]<-u
```

and I wanted to find the complexity of the algorithm.

The time complexity of INITIALIZE-SINGLE-SOURCE(G,s) is O(|V|).
The time complexity of the line 4 is O(1).
The time complexity of the line 5 is O(|V|).
The time complexity of the line 7 is O(log(|V|)).
The time complexity of the line 8 is O(1).
Which is the time complexityof the command S<-S U {u} ?
The line 10 is executed in total  O(Σ_{v \in V} deg(v))=O(E)  times and the time complexity of RELAX is O(1).

So the time complexity of the algorithm is equal to the time complexity of the lines (3-9)+O(E).
Which is the time complexity of the union?

Comment: Notice that the operation you were having trouble with is useless anyway since you never query `S` for anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So the time complexity of the algorithm is equal to the time
>   complexity of the lines (3-9)+O(E). Which is the time complexity of
>   the union?

No, it is not the complexity of the union, union can be done pretty efficiently if you are using hash table for example. Moreover, since you use `S` only for the union, it seems to be redundant.

The complexity of the algorithm also depends heavily on your `EXTRACT-MAX(Q)` function (usually it is logarithmic in the size of the `Q`, so logV per iteration), and on `RELAX(u,v,r)` (which is also usually logarithmic in the size of `Q`, since you need to update entries in your priority queue).

As expected, this brings us to the same complexity of original Dijkstra's algorithm, which is `O(E+VlogV)` or `O(ElogV)`, depending on implementation of your priority queue.

Comment: So is the time complexity of S<-S U {u} O(1)?

Comment: @evinda It really depends on the implementation of the union algorithm (which seems to be redundant here anyway), but it can be done in O(1), yes (by using a bit vector, for example, of size |V|).

Comment: So is it right as follows?


The time complexity of INITIALIZE-SINGLE-SOURCE(G,s) is O(|V|). The time complexity of the line 2 is O(1). The time complexity of the line 3 is O(|V|). The time complexity of the line 5 is O(log(|V|)). The time complexity of the lines 6,7 is O(1).
The time complexity of RELAX is O(log|V|) and so  he line 8 is executed in total O(Σ_{v \in V} deg(v)*log|V|)=O(E*log|V|) times.
So the time complexity of the algorithm is O(|V|)+O(1)+O(|V|*(log(|V|))+O(E*log|V|))=O(|V|+(|V|+|E|)*log|V|).

Comment: If so, how do we get that the time complexity is O(E+V*logV) ?

Comment: @evinda Actually, when assuming O(logV) for relaxation, it is indeed `O(ElogV)`, however, one can use a [fibonacci heap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_heap) to make the relaxation in `O(1)`, and then it is O(E+VlogV). For more details, wikipedia has pretty good section of complexity analysis for Dijkstra's algorithm: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm#Running_time

Comment: Thanks for your answer!!! Could you maybe also take a look at my other question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29871890/time-complexity-of-modified-dfs-algorithm ?

Answer (score 2):

I think that the solution should be based on the classic Dijkstra algorithm (complexity of which is well-known), as you suggested, however in your solution you define the "shortest path" problem incorrectly.

Note that the probability of A and B is p(A) * p(B) (if they're independent). Hence, you should find a path, whose **multiplication** of edges is **maximized**. Whereas Dijkstra algorithm finds the path whose **sum** of edges is **minimized**.

To overcome this issue you should define the weight of your edges as:

R*(u, v) = -log ( R(u, v) )

By introducing the logarithm, you convert multiplicative problem to additive.

Comment: I changed the algorithm RELAX so that multiplication of edges is maximized. And I also changed the initialization of the distances d[v]. So is it wrong?

Comment: I can't tell you for sure, I don't quite understand your pseudo-language. Anyway IMHO you should use exact Dijkstra algorithm (with appropriate edges weight).

Comment: @evinda I'd have a look at counterexamples to Dijkstra being used to find longest paths, which doesn't work (longest path is NP-hard). It is probably wrong.

Comment: @G.Bach Could you explain to me why the algorithm doesn't work?

Comment: @evinda I think I was wrong, it should be correct when all weights are between 0 and 1. The RELAX operation is basically what happens in the standard Dijkstra if we replace all weights by -log(r(u,v)). Still, it would be easier to take an implementation of Dijkstra for shortest path, and just replace all your weights accordingly.